# Python Regex-Keep Alpha Characters Continuously Adjacent/Inside Numeric Sequences

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract model numbers from a very messy string field in pandas.  The complication is that these serial numbers are not just numeric but sometimes alphanumeric.  What I am trying to accomplish is to create a regex capture group/combo that allows me to capture alpha characters ONLY when they continuously precede,end,or are inside numeric sequences:

```
model_number
part b: 101-03-0458B
B.2017Z brand name
brand - 027xY21
```

to

```
model_number_stripped
101030458B
B2017Z
027xY21
```

So far I have the following:

```
df['model_number_stripped'] = df['model_number'].str.replace('-','').str.replace('.','').str.replace('\D+','')
```

Comment: This seems difficult, since the `B` in the second row isn't technically adjacent to `2017Z`,  yet you want to capture that, while you don't want to capture the `d` in the third row which is also only separated by a special character from the numbers. For instance, if the third row were `brand.027xY21` I just don't see how you can distinguish this from the second row, unless you have some extra information, like the alpha characters you want to capture will always be capitalized, and there can only be at most X of them in a row.

Comment: This question is too broad. "part" is also alphanumeric. So is "brand". How is one supposed to know what kind of codes you're looking for.

Comment: @ALollz Yes, it is tricky.  I fixed the third row example to simplify (since it does not happen in real dataset).  It is OK so strip the characters '.' and '-' first.

Comment: @coldspeed To clarify, I want it to only keep alpha character wherever they are "touching" a numeric after stripping out the '.' and '-' characters.

Comment: Do I get it right you want to turn `B.2017ZZZZ.8` into `B2017ZZZZ8`? Try `.replace(r'\W+|(?<!\d)[^\W\d_](?!\S*\d)', '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, that is great.  I'm going to check it out.

Comment: If it is what you need, I will post an enhanced version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that definitely works for my needs.  Great job.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Happy to and upvoted.  You gave a nice comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df['model_number_stripped'] = df['model_number'].str.replace(r'\W+|(?<!\d)[^\W\d_](?![^\s\d]*\d)', '')
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCq3Tv/1)

**Details**

- `\W+` - 1 or more chars other than letters, digits and `_` (if you want to remove `_`, use `[\W_]+`)
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\d)[^\W\d_](?![^\s\d]*\d)` - any letter (`[^\W\d_]`) that is not preceded with a digit (`(?<!\d)`) and not followed with any 0+ chars other than whitespace and digit (`[^\s\d]*`) followed with a digit (`\d`). Note that `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind that, immediately to the left of the current location, requires the absence of a digit. The `(?![^\s\d]*\d)` pattern is a negative lookahead that fails the match if its pattern is found immediately to the right of the current location.